# What is the default scaling vector?

Tags: geometry

In many math puzzles and some proofs, especially concerning circles, the concept comes up of having one shape twice the size or twice as big as another.

Statements like these generally confuse me, as in example circles have a number of measurable quantities about them that grow at different rates; such as radius, circumference and surface.

Which of these values is supposed to be doubled to end up with the desired shape? Are there any solid math-grammatical rules concerning this?

Comment: Any linear quantity of the solid/surface.

Comment: Well, such statements should be properly defined. As you noticed, you could double the radius, the circumference or even the surface of a circle. What exactly is asked for should be obvious from the question; "should"... If you really need to guess (e.g. you can't ask anyone and really have to get this question right), I would suggest to go with the surface. If you don't need a number to input but should rather write an answer to the question, feel free to give the solution for all three, explaining that you did them all because the question wasn't clear. :) Still, if possible, ask.

Comment: Any properly written question should leave absolutely no ambiguity as to the correct interpretation of the question.  If you find a puzzlebook you are reading is consistently ambiguous, throw the book away and find a better book.  If you encounter this problem in an academic setting, ask for clarification from the teacher (*even during a test, this is strongly encouraged.  Although a teacher won't give information on how to solve a problem, they will generally gladly give information on how to interpret a problem*)

Comment: `a number of measurable quantities about them that grow at different rates; such as radius, circumference and surface` Radius and circumference grow at the same rate.

Comment: @dxiv I named both to outweigh the most obvious answer (to me) of the radius.